# How to properly send data to an opened Firefox sidebar?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to send data to a [sidebar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar). I've had a look at the following documentation, but I could not figure out how to properly send data over to the bar when it is already opened.

- [Communicating with sidebar scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar#Communicating_with_sidebar_scripts)
- [Communicating with other scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts)
- [Using ports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port)

My current approach is to save the `worker` object I get when the sidebar is attaching in a global variable, but I'm sure there is a better way. Minimal example showcasing my current approach:

```
var BARWORKER = undefined;
require("sdk/ui/sidebar").Sidebar({
    id: "mybar",
    url: "./sidebar.html",
    onReady: function (worker) {
        BARWORKER = worker;
    }
});

// lots of code

if (BARWORKER) {
    BARWORKER.port.emit("message", payload);
}

// lots of code
```

Answer (score 3):

To send data over to the sidebar when it is already opened you can also use the visibility API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

```
function onVisibilityChange() {
  if(!document.hidden){}
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChange);
```

Comment: Hey. I'm not quite following you there. Can you please add a few more details? I don't have access to the `document` global in the main script, from which I want to send data to the sidebar script. Thanks.

Comment: This code do you need add to the HTML in your sidebar.
If not your sidebar you can insert the code with **Content Script**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

Comment: Ok, that is basically the documentation I already linked to in my question. I still need a complete, working example.

Answer (score 2):

My current solution is to give the sidebar a field to save the current `worker` object. Upon detaching the sidebar it is set to `undefined`.
This works pretty well as an intermediate solution. I have a feeling that the best approach would involve custom events, however I have not found out how to use one in this specific case yet.

```
var BAR = require("sdk/ui/sidebar").Sidebar({
    id: "mybar",
    url: "./sidebar.html",
    worker: undefined,
    onReady: function (worker) {
        BAR.worker = worker;
    },
    onDetach: function () {    
        BAR.worker = undefined;
    }
});
```